# Must override or implement a supertype

Tags: java

I have a class named `Mission`
which contains

```
public abstract void onEvent(final IMissionEvent event);
```

and another class named `MissionKill` which extends Mission

Now on `MissionKill` i use the following:

```
@Override
public void onEvent(final MissionEventLogin event)
{
    // My code here
}
```

`MissionEventLogin` is implementing `IMissionEvent`
I want use on `MissionKill` the `public void onEvent(final MissionEventLogin event)`
Using the MissionEventLogin class which implements the `ImissionEvent` but it won't let me unless i cast it. The problem is i don't want to cast each time like:

```
@Override
public void onEvent(final IMissionEvent event)
{
    final MissionEventLogin login = (MissionEventLogin) event;
    
    //CODE
}
```

Is there any other way so i can pass new classes that implements IMissionEvent without cast required?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the cast, use generics:

```
public class Mission<T extends IMissionEvent> {
    public abstract void onEvent(T event);
    // other stuff
}

public class MissionKill extends Mission<MissionEventLogin> {
    public abstract void onEvent(MissionEventLogin event) {
        // do something with event
    }
}
```

---

Note that using `final` for method parameters is an anti-pattern, especially for an `abstract` method signature, where it is meaningless and ignored by the compiler.

Comment: Great usage. It works fine, but just for learning is there any other way?

Comment: By the way i get raw warnings is there any better way to improve this?
```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public Mission<IMissionEvent> getMission(final int id)
 {
  return MISSION.stream().filter(s -> s.getId() == id).findFirst().orElse(null);
 }

 /**
  * @return {@code list} of all {@code Mission}
  */
 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
 public List<Mission> getMissions()
 {
  return MISSION;
 }```

Comment: @Girlsarebeautiful You need to type references to `Mission`, eg instead of `public List<Mission> getMissions()` code `public List<MissionKill> getMissions()` or `public <T extends IMissionEvent> List<Mission<T>> getMissions()` depending on what you’re trying to do.